# Check if IIS is installed via .BAT

Tags: windows, batch-file, iis, cmd

I'm using the `cmd` commands bellow to install IIS on my machine, as suggested [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-from-the-command-line).

```
start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;
IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ASP;IIS-CGI;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-ODBCLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;
IIS-WindowsAuthentication;IIS-DigestAuthentication;IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication;IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication;IIS-URLAuthorization;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-IPSecurity;
IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-ManagementService;IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;IIS-Metabase;IIS-WMICompatibility;IIS-LegacyScripts;IIS-LegacySnapIn;IIS-FTPPublishingService;IIS-FTPServer;IIS-FTPManagement;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI
```

I want to check first if it's already installed using CMD to include an `if` in my batch script. How can I do this using `cmd`?

Comment: you can check the registry entries

Comment: Can you give me more details on that?

Answer (score 1):

As I have no installed IIS I can't fully test this. You can use the [registry entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components) to check the version, installation dir and so on. You can use this in order to see if the IIS is installed:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\VersionString" >nul 2>&1 && (
 echo  installed 
)||(
 echo NOT installed 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @npocmaka said in the first comment of my question, and also by following the explanation on this [WEBPAGE](https://help.upcurvecloud.com/wmobile/howto_verify_aspnet_installed.html)

I've created this `.bat` file.

```
@echo off
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp /v VersionString

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto NOT_EXISTS

:EXISTS
    echo "IIS installed :-)"
    goto:END
:NOT_EXISTS
    echo "IIS not installed :-( ... Begin installation"
    start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;
        IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ASP;IIS-CGI;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-ODBCLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;
        IIS-WindowsAuthentication;IIS-DigestAuthentication;IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication;IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication;IIS-URLAuthorization;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-IPSecurity;
        IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-ManagementService;IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;IIS-Metabase;IIS-WMICompatibility;IIS-LegacyScripts;IIS-LegacySnapIn;IIS-FTPPublishingService;IIS-FTPServer;IIS-FTPManagement;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI
    goto:END
:END
pause
```

Comment: On Windows 10 : This does not work if you have installed IIS, previously - but later uninstalled it.